# Handling additional information in doc2vec training

Tags: doc2vec

I'd like to train doc2vec on items consisting of 2 bits of information:
a) text (in legal domain)
b) keywords and/or references to other legal texts extracted from the text 
I want my model to be able to identify similar texts according to, basically, 2 criteria: 
a) textual similarity and b) presence of keywords/references

Are there any best practices for a case such as this? 
My ideas so far:
- join text and keywords/referenes into a single string and train a model on that 
- train two independent models (two vectors will be produced: for text and for keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by 'doc2vec' you mean the `gensim` implementation of the 'Paragraph Vector' algorithm, in the class `Doc2Vec`.

Both of your approaches might work and could be worth testing. There's no facility in the `Doc2Vec` class for feeding distinctly "other" data in, but you can make that data look like extra word-tokens, or extra `tags`, and thus have the cross-correlations of those other values affect, and be embedded within, the resulting vector-space.

Specifically, if you want your "keywords and/or references" to be modeled alongside the whole text, and not just the normal-words they might happen-to-be-next-to (if they were appended to the text), you should especially try one or both options of:

- using the PV-DBOW mode (`dm=0`), which does not use word-to-nearby-word influences (within a context `window`)
- placing the keywords or references as extra `tags`, in addition to unique-to-the-document ID tag (that's the classic way of naming doc-vectors)

(If trying two separate models, you might have the model based on natural texts still use PV-DM modes affected by a `window`, while the essentially unordered-nature of keywords/references would use a PV-DBOW mode.)

Comment: thanks, does placing extra data as tags affect training results? I would assume a tags are basically a unique id for the document, aren’t they?

Comment: In the original/classic use of `Doc2Vec`, yes, each doc has just a single ID. But gensim supports a logical extension of more than one doc-vector per doc – such as a known category that repeats over many docs. (It's vaguely like synthesizing another composite doc, of all docs in that category, and giving it the category as its unique ID.) Whether this is a beneficial approach or not will depend on a lot of things. In particular, you don't want many more total tags than docs and you don't want multiple unique tags per doc – either would tend to 'dilute' whatever could be learned from a doc.

Comment: But, such extra tags are a bit like "floating words" over the whole doc, without a specific position that's only close-to-some-words. That might better fit the special role of refs/keywords than in in-text placement. Whether it works for you would have to be tested - there's few rules-of-thumb, and it all depends on your data, goals, and specific model parameters.